# linear response for a simple harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, linear-systems

Really sorry for this simple question, but I think it will be useful/interesting in general.

Consider a quantum simple harmonic oscillator.
Add a perturbation $H_I = -\lambda \hat{x}$

Calculate $\langle \psi| \hat{x} |\psi \rangle$ in the new ground state, to first order in perturbation theory in $\lambda$, and relate it to $\langle 0| x^2 |0 \rangle $ where $| 0 \rangle$ is the unperturbed ground state.

Can someone help me on this

Comment: Note that the homework tag "Applies to questions of primarily educational value - **not only questions that arise from actual homework assignments** (emphasis mine), but any question where it is preferable to guide the asker to the answer rather than giving it away outright." So where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I think the [Hellmann-Feynman theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellmann%E2%80%93Feynman_theorem) might be of use here.